# Android Studio [Install_Failed_Insufficient_Storage]

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, storage, failed-installation

I have a problem with installing an apk of my app on my phone from Android Studio. Every time i tried i got this error message:

```
09/10 22:40:00: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\pokef\AndroidStudioProjects\Runescape\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.myapps.myproductions.rsstats.
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.myapps.myproductions.rsstats."
pkg: /data/local/com.myapps.myproductions.rsstats.
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]


$ adb shell pm uninstall com.myapps.myproductions.rsstats.
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APK
```

I know there are a lot of threads out there talking about this problem, but Ive already tried everything. Im certain i have enough storage, i cleared all caches, i uninstalled all previous versions, i changed the manifest to "android:installLocation="preferExternal" , i restarted my phone etc, so please dont mark this as a duplicate.

This problem only happens since i changed the package path from com.example.myapp etc. to com.myapps.myproductions.rsstats.
Im sure that I correctly adapted all paths in the files to this location. What else could I try?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the command-line to install your app rather than doing it directly from Android Studio?

Comment: If you insist on using the command line, you can save a little bit of typing by using `adb install` and `adb uninstall`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How much storage do you have free? The system won't let the free storage space go below 200-300MB. Also, please don't end your package name with a dot(this may be the issue, but the error message suggests otherwise)

Comment: Over 3 gigs, and I dont have a point in the name, it just added that

Comment: Well, according to the code log you provided the package name indeed has a dot

Comment: @SimonHostettler The settings and all of your code may not have a dot at the end, but you added one in the `adb` commands. Try running the commands again without the dot at the end of the package name.

Comment: Wow, that actually was the problem, I dont know how that got there, thank you very much.

Answer (score 31):

This happens when you have installed many versions of different apps on the virtual device.
Just stop the device. Open AVD Manager and right click on the `device` `>` `Wipe Data`.
like in the pic.
[image]

Comment: If you Wipe Data you lose all apps and data e.g. if you have WhatsApp installed you will lose all chats and you will have reinstall WhatsApp again. I won't really advise it.

Answer (score 4):

Since you claim to have enough storage free on the phone (**I would recommend to have at least 500MB free**) As suggested also by Aenadon, the problem could be the "." at the end of the package name.

Google suggests to name the packages with a reverse URL. for example:

*com.mycompanyname.appname*

by no means should end with a dot.

Answer (score 4):

I got the INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE and the solution is to uninstall the app then re-install it - the issue is caused by having the different versions of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue in my device with 64 GB internal storage with 1.3 GB free.
I solved it simply doing my internal storage free by

> deleting about 1 GB videos

because already the installed apps was not useless.

Answer (score -2):

Check your device storage space on which you are installing your app.
Delete some data if space is running out.
It happens because when you write bytes the size of that file became very large and thus this error occur  (i am getting this error)